# How can I manipulate data that comes from a csv file in java?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, algorithm, timestamp

I am trying to build a program in spring that reads files and does calculations with the data that comes from the files.
What interests me more from the file is Timestamp, Code and State. I want to calculate the Timestamp difference between two different states.
To calculate this difference I have to keep in mind that the state UN should either go to ACK or RTNUN. From ACK/RTNUN it can go to NORM, but not any other form. For example RTNUN to ACK is considered an error and no calculations are done. (The code should be the same for both states).
State UPR can only go to NORM. The rest is considered an error and no calculations are done.

File Structure example:

```
Timestamp;ISPPE;Sequence;Code;Severity;State;Subsystem;
2023-06-08T13:03:22.653+0200;1223085273;1;FW|110|;E;UN;;
2023-06-08T13:03:28.498+0200;1223091118;1;FW|110|;E;ACK;;
2023-06-08T13:03:28.499+0200;1223091119;1;FW|110|;E;RTNUN;;
2023-06-08T13:03:28.500+0200;1223091120;1;FW|110|;E;NORM;;
2023-06-08T13:04:44.546+0200;1223167018;1;FW|110|;E;UN;;
2023-06-08T13:04:56.750+0200;1223179222;1;FW|110|;E;RTNUN;;
2023-06-08T13:04:56.750+0200;1223179222;2;FW|110|;E;NORM;;
2023-06-08T13:05:33.230+0200;1223215702;1;FW|110|;E;UN;;
2023-06-08T13:05:33.500+0200;1223215972;1;FW|110|;E;RTNUN;;
2023-06-08T13:05:33.500+0200;1223215972;2;FW|110|;E;NORM;;
2023-06-08T13:13:32.562+0200;1223693667;1;FW|110|;E;UN;;
2023-06-08T13:13:32.861+0200;1223693966;1;FW|110|;E;RTNUN;;
2023-06-08T13:13:32.861+0200;1223693966;2;FW|110|;E;NORM;;
2023-06-08T14:33:57.021+0200;1228506046;1;FW|115|;I;UN;Media Input;
2023-06-08T14:35:02.177+0200;1228571031;1;FW|5|;E;UN;Carriage;
2023-06-08T14:35:06.998+0200;1228575852;1;FW|5|;E;RTNUN;Carriage;
2023-06-08T14:35:06.998+0200;1228575852;2;FW|5|;E;NORM;Carriage;
2023-06-21T10:21:28.379+0200;898472;1;FW|2|0.1;F;UPR;E-Module;
2023-06-21T10:21:28.380+0200;898473;1;FW|2|1.0;F;NORM;E-Module;
2023-06-08T14:35:59.566+0200;1228628130;1;FW|110|;E;UN;Media Output Roll;
2023-06-08T14:35:59.634+0200;1228628198;1;FW|115|;I;RTNUN;Media Input Roll;
2023-06-08T14:35:59.634+0200;1228628198;2;FW|115|;I;NORM;Media Input Roll;
2023-06-08T14:35:59.638+0200;1228628202;1;FW|110|;E;RTNUN;Media Output Roll;
2023-06-08T14:35:59.638+0200;1228628202;2;FW|110|;E;NORM;Media Output Roll;
```

I will take an example of the first two lines code `FW|110|` passes from `UN` state to `ACK` state. So it is an allowed state change. In this moment I need to calculate how long did this state change took. In this case it would the difference between 2023-06-08T13:03:22.653+0200 and 2023-06-08T13:03:28.498+0200. The output can be different as long as time difference is part of it. An output example Sequence -> timeDiff. So key would be 1223085273 and value 5845, which is the difference in millisecond.s The goal is to find how long it took a specific Code to change state (that are allowed).

The state changes randomly. It is called a state change when it has the same code and a regular state. For example it can start at the first row with UN state and change state at the last row.

What I am currently doing is reading the file and putting the data in a list of String list, and loop through it, but there are too many edge cases and I feel like it is not the right approach.

Right now I'm looping through the whole data that I get from the file, but my code is messy due to too many if statements

I would appreciate if anyone can give me other ideas or approach.

Comment: On Stack Overflow, your post must focus on a single question. You seem to be asking about how to (a) parse CSV, and (b) make calculations across rows. The first has been addressed many times on existing Questions and Answers. The second should be its own post, and should be more carefully explained.

Comment: What is the expected result for your sample input above? How should the expected result look like?

Comment: You need to build a 'state machine', maybe something [like this?](https://www.baeldung.com/java-enum-simple-state-machine)

Comment: Design a class to represent the information from a line from the CSV. In your class represent the timestamp as `OffsetDateTime` and the state as an enum. Use a library that can read CSV, there are some out there, also some free ones. When your code detects a legal state change, calculate the difference using `ChronoUnit.MILLIS.between()`, for example `ChronoUnit.MILLIS.between(row1.getTimestammp(), row2.getTimestamp())`.

Comment: Is a state change from one line to the next, or from one line to the next line having the same code, or how is it?? And are you asking us to design data structure and algorithm for you??? I am sorry to say, I still find the question both too broad and unclear.

Comment: You need to design your state machine first. The time delta aspect is relatively trivial once you've done that

Comment: Your comments are really helpful. Please always add more information *as edits to the original question* so we have everything in one place. I added a couple times for you. Next time it’s your turn. :-)

Comment: One idea is: Once you have designed your Java class, say, `LineInfo` (poor name, find a better one), use a `Map<String, LineInfo>` to hold the last line for each code. For each `LineInfo` read from CSV, check if the code is already in the map, if it is, whether the state change from the last state to the new one is legal, and if it is, calculate the time difference.  Under all circumstances add the new `LineInfo` to the map in place of the old one.

Answer (score 2):

CSV files are an easy to read format - in general.
And then, due to format insufficiencies they come with a lot of addons or exceptions. Just think of storing strings that shall contain commas and linefeeds as value.

To not have to either create another quirky format but use already developed and tested code, you may want to use the [Apache Commons CSV](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/) library.

Reading an Excel-compatible CSV may look like this:

```
Reader in = new FileReader("path/to/file.csv");
Iterable<CSVRecord> records = CSVFormat.EXCEL.parse(in);
for (CSVRecord record : records) {
    String lastName = record.get("Last Name");
    String firstName = record.get("First Name");
}
```

Next step is to check the time difference between events. For that parse the timestamp into Instant using [Instant.parse()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Instant.html#parse(java.lang.CharSequence)).

Once you have two Instant's calculate their difference using [Duration.between()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Duration.html#between(java.time.temporal.Temporal,java.time.temporal.Temporal)).